# First part of the proof of Theorem 8.30 - Mathematical Analysis 2nd ed. - Apostol

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

"*The next theorem gives an example of a divergent series whose partial sums are bounded. This is the geometric series $\sum z^n$ with $|z|=1$, that is, with $z=e^{ix}$ where $x$ is real.*"

**Theorem 8.30.** For every real $x\neq 2m\pi$ *(m is an integer)*, we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^ne^{ikx}=e^{ix}\frac{1-e^{inx}}{1-e^{ix}}=\frac{\sin(nx/2)}{\sin(x/2)}e^{\frac{i(n+1)x}{2}}\qquad (1)$$

Now, although I can understand the first equality in (1), I can't grasp the second equality.

The proof of this theorem shows that

$$e^{ix}\frac{1-e^{inx}}{1-e^{ix}}=\frac{e^{inx/2}-e^{-inx/2}}{e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2}}e^{\frac{i(n+1)x}{2}}$$

Here are my two questions:

1. If the partial sums are bounded, isn't the sequence of the partial sums convergent? And if the sequence of the partial sums is convergent, shouldn't the series converge? What I'm misunderstanding?
2. Could you kindly help me understand how to find the second equality?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No.  For a specific example using the series cited in the theorem, choose $x = \pi$, so that $a_k = e^{\pi i k} = (-1)^k$.  Then the series becomes $(-1) + 1 + (-1) + 1 + \cdots$.  Its partial sums are then $\{-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, \ldots\}$.  Bounded, but very clearly not convergent.
2. The second equality is simply an application of Euler's formula $$e^{iz} = \cos z + i \sin z:$$  we then have $e^{-iz} = \cos (-z) + i \sin (-z) = \cos z - i \sin z$, from which we get $e^{iz} - e^{-iz} = 2i \sin z$, and $\sin z = (e^{iz} - e^{-iz})/(2i)$.  The result immediately follows from the equation you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

If $\sum_n u_n$ is a **positive series** then it's a convergent series if and only if its partial sum is bounded above. This result isn't true if the series has a general term $u_n$ which changes sign or for complex series. For example the series
$$\sum_n (-1)^n$$
is clearly divergent although its partial sum is bounded.

The second equality is obtained using the identity
$$e^{ix}-e^{-ix}=2i\sin x$$